# Java | Json String to Object without library

Tags: java, objective-c, json, object, j2objc

I want to convert a Json String to an object, without out a library. The reason is that I want to convert the Java code with J2Objc into a Objective-C file. And J2Objc doesn't allow libraries as far as I know. Does anyone know an answer to this question?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

J2Objc does actually support libraries, as explained in [the docs](http://j2objc.org/docs/). The are plugins available for [eclipse](http://j2objc.org/docs/Using-J2ObjC-with-Eclipse.html), [maven](http://j2objc.org/docs/Using-J2ObjC-with-Maven.html) and [gradle](http://j2objc.org/docs/Using-J2ObjC-with-Gradle.html) that handle everything for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But when I add the library as an internal, I get "The import com.google.gson.Gson cannot be resolved".

Comment: What build system are you using? What is your full build-script/file whatever?

Comment: I am using MacOS and try to transalte it with the terminal, not the eclipse plugin. And my file is just a normal Java file with an gson implementation. I have tried to put it in the lib directory and then I tried to put it on the same level as the Java file.

Comment: I really recommend you to switch to a real build system eg. gradle, it will make your life a lot easier. I don't know how to get J2Objc to translate the libraries using the command line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128571/discussion-between-todd-sewell-and-user6586661).